# Crowdsourcing - Snowflake differentiators from Azure's DW offering

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm curious as to the differentiating factors between Snowflake and Azure SQL data warehouse (recently rebranded as Synapse).

What are the factors that Snowflake uses to emphasize its superiority over Azure's DW offering?

Why did or would you choose Snowflake over Azure?

Answer (score 3):

What I've found so far:
SF = Snowflake
Sy = Azure Synapse

- Only one setting per DB for compute power on Sy, while SF allows
  multiple virtual warehouses.  Also the scaling capabilities (up and
  out) of SF virtual warehouses allow for greater control and tuning vs
  the single concept of data warehouse units (DWU) in Sy.
- Sy requires manual maintenance of statistics and doesn't seem to have the SF
  advantages of the Columnar storage
- I'm not finding any matching
  functionality in Sy to compete with SF's semi-structured
  functionality.
- Sy is attempting to include a Hadoop flavored
  architecture and functionality, but all of that is still listed as
  "Preview" at this point.

Sy seems about 3 years behind SF.

Answer (score 1):

```
The big differences are in scalability.  There are limits to the size and compute capacity available to Azure Synapse Analytics.   Azure SA has a limit of 128 concurrent queries and for row store type tables it has a size limit of 60TB compressed for one table (No limit for column store tables).  There's also a limit to the amount of compute resources you can apply to a particular database.  The limitations are listed here..
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-service-capacity-limits

For Snowflake there are no practical limits on database or compute size.  You can allocate Warehouses(compute) or clusters of warehouses to accommodate any workload.